# How to get the Process Environment Block (PEB) from extern process?

Tags: delphi, winapi, api

I want to get the PEB from the "notepad.exe" process. Does someone know how to do it?

I tried the `GetModuleHandle` API, but it doesn't return a valid pointer (it return zero every time) because I have to be the caller process of that module.

For that reason, I want to know how to get it to work with `EnumProcessModules` or `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Matt Pietrek described how to do that in a [1994 *Under the Hood* column](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matt_pietrek/archive/2004/08/25/220330.aspx). It was about how to get the environment variables of another process, where the first step is to get a pointer to the PEB. To do that, he says, call [`NtQueryInformationProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684280.aspx). The `PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION` structure it fills contains the base address of the PEB structure. (You'll need to use `ReadProcessMemory` to read it since the address will be in the context of the external process's address space, not yours.)

To call `NtQueryInformationProcess`, you'll need a handle to the process. If you started the process yourself (by calling `CreateProcess`), then you already have a handle. Otherwise, you'll need to find the process ID and then call `OpenProcess`. To get the process ID, search for the process you want with `EnumProcesses` or `Process32First`/`Process32Next`. (I prefer the latter because it provides more information with less work.)

Comment: It should be noted that a WOW64 process has two PEB's and that complicates things a little bit IIRC

Comment: @Anders is correct.  `ZwQueryInformationProcess` returns the PEB that matches the bitness of the _calling_ process.  In the case where a 32-bit (WOW64) process attempts to retrieve the PEB of a native 64-bit process, `PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION.PebBaseAddress` is NULL, since native 64-bit processes have no 32-bit PEB.  Also note that the 32-bit and 64-bit PEBs have different structure offsets, so this method would have to be modified for a 64-bit process to successfully read from a 32-bit PEB.

Comment: There is a comment in the [`NtQueryInformationProcess()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684280.aspx) documentation that says: "*... when querying a process running under wow64 ... the PebBaseAddress returned is actually for the 64-bit modules loaded under wow64 ... **the PEB which pertains to 32-bit modules can be found by taking the PebBaseAddress and subtracting one page (0x1000) from its value**...*"

Comment: Apparently that will not work from Windows 8 onward anymore, but [this code](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dynamorio-users/wf0tcp420m0) provides an alternative that retrieves the 32bit PEB address from the 32bit TEB.