# Ctypes __readgsqword

Tags: python, windows, winapi, ctypes

When trying to return the value of PEB in python you run into an issue similar to this, is it not possible to call __readgsqword in python.

```
def GetPEB():
    return ctypes.windll.kernel32.__readgsqword('0x0C',ctypes.sizeof('PVOID'))
```

```
AttributeError: function '__readgsqword' not found
```

Comment: if want get `PEB` address of current process can use `RtlGetCurrentPeb()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those functions are, as explained at the documentation, intrinsic functions and not exported by the kernel 32 dll.

You could call them by compiling a DLL that exposed those functions, and then call that from your Python code.

However, you'd likely be better using a different approach. For instance: [How to access the PEB of another process with python ctypes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35106511/505088)