# Trying to convert MASM into C equivalent, but getting different result

Tags: c, windows, masm, portable-executable

I was trying to convert this MASM code

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall 
.stack 4096
assume fs:nothing

.code 
    main proc
            mov eax, [fs:30h]           ; Pointer to PEB (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block)
            mov eax, [eax + 0ch]        ; Pointer to Ldr
            mov eax, [eax + 14h]        ; Pointer to InMemoryOrderModuleList
            mov eax, [eax]                ; this program's module
            mov eax, [eax]                ; ntdll module
            mov eax, [eax -8h + 18h]; kernel32.DllBase
            
            mov ebx, 0                    ; just so we can put a breakpoint on this
            int 3
    main endp
    end main
```

which finds Kernel32 dll base, into C equivalent.  This is my try:

```c
    asm("mov %fs:0x30, %eax\n"); // PEB
    asm("mov 0x0c(%eax), %eax\n"); // LDR
    asm("mov 0x14(%eax), %eax\n"); // InMemoryOrderModuleList
    asm("mov %eax, %eax"); // this program's module
    asm("mov %eax, %eax"); // ntdll module
    asm("mov -0x8(%eax), %eax"); // kernel32.DllBase
    asm("mov 0x18(%eax), %eax"); // kernel32.DllBase
    asm("mov %%eax, %0 \n" : "=r"(i));
    asm("int3");
    printf("kernel32.DllBase: %p\n", i);
```

The compiler I'm using is i686-w64-mingw32-gcc.

For some reason the code I wrote returns wrong address. The address it returns points to ntdll.

[image]

Comment: Don't you need parenthesis around the first `%eax` on lines 4 and 5? (also, should those \n characters be there?, and if yes, should they not be on every line?)

Comment: The parenthesis! I overlooked it. Thanks!

Comment: Is there some reason you feel like you have to write this in asm?  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37288289/2189500) C code shows how to find PEB, after that it's just reading from a struct.  Alternately, doesn't `GetModuleHandle` return a pointer to the address?  If asm is a requirement, I'd encourage you to use extended asm, since basic asm explicitly [states](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Basic-Asm.html): *Do not expect a sequence of asm statements to remain perfectly consecutive after compilation.*  One extended asm that outputs the value is a better choice.

Comment: It's a pet project, I'm just experimenting with inline assembly and PE file parsing. Thanks for the advice, I'll try to rewrite the sequence into an extended asm.